# Replacing html content using sed and regex

Tags: linux, bash, web-scraping, sed

I am trying to replace the content of some HTML content using sed in a bash script. For some reason I'm not getting the proper result as it's not replacing anything mainly the regex part

HTML i want to replace

```
<h3 class="indicate-hover css-5fzt5q">For the Most Complex Heroines Animation
<h3 class="indicate-hover css-1pvrrwb">The Psychology Behind Sibling
```

to

```
 head For the Most Complex Heroines Animation
 head The Psychology Behind Sibling
```

i used

```
  sed -e 's/<h3 class="indicate-hover css-([a-b0-9]+)">/head/g'
```

mainly ([a-b0-9]) this part is getting failed in execution , i must be missing something out,i want to get it more specific , i have `"<p class="summary-class css-1azn4ub">How many words can"` i want to substitute it to 'tail ' and have many more other tags . The regex part is giving me the pain

Comment: I tried : sed -E 's/<h3 class="indicate-hover css-([a-b0-9])">/head/g' and sed -e 's/<h3 class="indicate-hover css-([a-b0-9]\+)">/head/g'  still no satisfactory results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*-[[:alnum:]]\+">/head /' input_file
```

**Output**

```
head For the Most Complex Heroines Animation
head The Psychology Behind Sibling
```

Comment: actually i want to get it more specific , i have "<p class="summary-class css-1azn4ub">How many words can"   i want to substitute it to 'tail ' and have many more other tags . The regex part is giving me the pain

Comment: @Debankan Please check edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\+`, unless you use `sed -E`

- `\+` is a valid quantifier in the (default) Basic regular expressions
- `+` is a valid quantifier in Extended regular expressions